# JSF PrimeFaces dynamic dataTable Map

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Struggling with dynamic table content on PrimeFaces & dataTable.
The goal is to render table column headers & content dynamically.

Here is my bean code:

```
@ManagedBean(name="treeBean")
@SessionScoped
public class TreeBean implements Serializable {
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(TreeBean.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private List<TableColHeader> tableColHeaderList;

    /** Project-specific data structure. One list entry per one table row, Integer in Map is number of column */
    private List<Map<Integer,String>> tableContent;

    public TreeBean() {
        tableColHeaderList=MockedDataProvider.getDemo1ColHeaderList();
        tableContent=MockedDataProvider.getDemo1TableContent();     
        log.info("TreeBean started");
    }

    public int getTableColHeaderIndex(TableColHeader tableColHeader) {
        return tableColHeaderList.indexOf(tableColHeader);
    } 

    public List<TableColHeader> getTableColHeaderList() {
        return tableColHeaderList;
    }

    public void setTableColHeaderList(List<TableColHeader> tableColHeaderList) {
        this.tableColHeaderList = tableColHeaderList;
    }

    public List<Map<Integer,String>>  getTableContent() {
        return tableContent;
    }

    public void setTableContent(List<Map<Integer,String>> tableContent) {
        this.tableContent = tableContent;
    }   

    public List<Integer> getTableContentIdKeysAsList(int id){
         return new ArrayList<Integer>(tableContent.get(id).keySet());
    }   
}
```

TableColHeader.java - as model:

```
public class TableColHeader {   
    private String propertyUri;
    private String label;
    private String unitLabel;
    private String unitUri;
//getters,setters,equals,hashCode..
}
```

And here are my JSF page dataTable code:

```
<p:dataTable id="queryResults" var="tableContentVar" value="#{treeBean.tableContent}">                                               
   <p:columns value="#{tableBean.tableColHeaderList}" var="column"  >  
     <f:facet name="header">  
     #{column.label}  
     </f:facet>                       
     <h:outputText value="#{tableContentVar.values().toArray()[treeBean.getTableColHeaderIndex(column)]}" /> 
   </p:columns>                                                       
</p:dataTable>
```

I've read about issues with empty columnIndexVar value as https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=4449, but getting index from bean doesn't help too.

I just see nothing on the place where dataTable should be, and no exceptions as well.
Any ideas, please?

Using Primefaces 3.5 & JBoss 7.1.1.Final.

Comment: Where is `tableContentMap` and `tableContentVar` defined?

Comment: @Sergii you should write `tableContentVar`?

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking it right now..

Comment: Fixed `tableContentVar/tableContentMap`, same trouble still existing

Comment: Do you get any Exception? Are you sure that `#{treeBean.tableContent}` has any value? and does `tableColHeaderList` in `tableBean` have any value?

Comment: @Sergii Name of your backing bean is `treeBean` but in `p:columns` you are referencing `tableBean`?

Comment: `treeBean` vs `tableBean` - that's it ! Thank you! Now works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @partlov, the wrong thing here was referencing to `tableBean` instead on `treeBean` in JSF code.

So here is working code:

```
<p:dataTable id="queryResults" var="tableContentVar" value="#{treeBean.tableContent}" >                                              
    <p:columns value="#{treeBean.tableColHeaderList}" var="column"  >  
    <f:facet name="header">  
     #{column.label}  
     </f:facet>                       
    <h:outputText value="#{tableContentVar.values().toArray()[treeBean.getTableColHeaderIndex(column)]}" /> 
    </p:columns>                                                      
</p:dataTable>
```